# Unable to pass String Array list from one dart file to another dart file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a string list (selectedValue1) and I want to push this list to another dart file.

So, here is what I have tried.

In the 1st dart file, in Navigator.push, I have provided something like this.

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                   MyApp( 
                      selectedValue11: selectedValue1
                   )),
 );
```

and in the 2nd dart file, I have declared a string list at global level (Hoping that it can be accessed in Stateful widget class too) and called it inside a constructor of Stateless widget.

```
List<String> selectedValue11 = [];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  
  MyApp({Key? key, @required selectedValue11} ) : super(key: key);
    

   //MyApp({selectedValue11});
   

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("selectedValue11");
    print(selectedValue11);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      
    );
  }
}
```

But, I am unable to retrieve data in 2nd dart file.

[image]

It would be great if you guys can throw some light on this!

Answer (score 0):

Global Variables can be accessed from anywhere.

Im not sure if i'm correctly following what you are trying to do here, but you should store and handle mutable state in the "State" of a "StatefulWidget", or use some state management solution like provider, or bloc, etc.

I can't think of a good use case for global variables.

As for your example: can you maybe provide the full code?

For the code snippets you provided, your constructor of **MyApp** has an unused param **selectedValue11**.
This is not the way to set the global variable. It can instead be accessed from anywhere directly. The constructor is used to initialize member variables of that class.

**Edit:** the following example should show the difference between class member variables and global variables. You can also run it and navigate back and forward between those pages and see how the global variable changes.

File 1:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: File1()));

class File1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              globalSelectedValues.add("global");
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      const File2(localSelectedValues: <String>["local", "local", "local"]),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text("Change global value and Navigate"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

File 2:

```
List<String> globalSelectedValues = <String>[];

class File2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> localSelectedValues;

  const File2({super.key, required this.localSelectedValues});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Text("Global: $globalSelectedValues")),
          Center(child: Text("Local: $localSelectedValues")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for stepping forward and giving your solution. However, when I tried this, I am not able to see the string list being printed in MyApp(). I am trying to pass a string list (Maid 1 and Maid 2) into a different dart file (file which has myApp() class).Myapp() dart file is being used to export the string list in CSV format (Using syncfusion_flutter_xlsio). I am not finding a way to send you the full code in comments. If there is any, I am happy to send you.

Comment: I editted my answer to provide you a full example for passing variables. 
Do you have a public github repository for your code? 
Or if its not that much, just edit your question with the full code snippets of the files.

Comment: Have you resolved your other problem?